# Embedding react-boilerplate in Rails 5.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, react-boilerplate

Has anyone tried integrating [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) into a Ruby on Rails 5.1 app? It looks like the [5.1 approach to embedding React components in views](https://medium.com/@hpux/rails-5-1-loves-javascript-a1d84d5318b) is fairly simple. Rails 5.1 is using [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) which has its approach to mixing Ruby configuration with Webpack. It doesn't seem very straightforward, but does anyone have any techniques for accomplishing this?

Comment: "integrating" is not very clear. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically using the new approach of putting components in app/assets but with all of Redux , Saga, and Router included in React boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `rails-react-boilerplate`. The `README.md` should have all the info you need to get up and running. You should be able to easily find it on github.